# How do i get cookies from libcurl?

Tags: libcurl

I visit 4pages. Each page set cookies. How do i ask libcurl for either all cookies or the value of a specific cookie like "session_id"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)() with the [CURLINFO_COOKIELIST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOCOOKIELIST) option is perfect for this: